# Named query not known :: DropWizard Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

I have an entity class defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "SomeTable.getSomeTableForAmount",
                query = "select x from SomeTable x where :amount >= x.startingAmount AND :amount <= x.endingAmount " +
                        "AND product = :product"
        )
})

@Getter
@Setter
public class SomeTable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private BigDecimal startingAmount;
    private BigDecimal endingAmount;
    private BigDecimal minimumDueAmount;
    private Product product;
}
```

The DAO for the class looks like:

```
public class SomeTableDao extends AbstractDAO<SomeTable> implements ISomeTableDao {
    @Inject
    public SomeTableDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<SomeTable> getSomeTableForAmount(BigDecimal amount, Product product) {
        return namedQuery("SomeTable.getSomeTableForAmount")
                .setParameter("amount", amount)
                .setParameter("product", product)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .list()
                .stream()
                .map(s -> (SomeTable) s)
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

On execution of this from a resource, I face exception stating `Named query not known: SomeTable.getSomeTableForAmount`

The resource method is annotated with `@UnitOfWork`.

I also noticed that the query does not get added to `namedQueryDefinitionMap` in `NamedQueryRepository`.

Comment: Maybe instead of `namedQuery("SomeTable.getMinimumDueForAmount")` you want to use `namedQuery("SomeTable.getSomeForAmount")`

Comment: @SternK Does the name really matter? As I have already added this into `@NamedQueries` in my entity class.

Comment: Also tried changing the name across all the places, doesn't work.
I noticed that the query does not get added to namedQueryDefinitionMap in NamedQueryRepository.

Comment: Please show your method `namedQuery` definition.

Answer (score 1):

As you have named your query `SomeTable.getSomeTableForAmount`, your code is trying to find a constant `getSomeTableForAmount` for this named query in the `Sometable` class.

Try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "SomeTable.getSomeTableForAmount",
                query = "select x from SomeTable x where :amount >= x.startingAmount AND :amount <= x.endingAmount " +
                        "AND product = :product"
        )
})

@Getter
@Setter
public class SomeTable {

    public static final String getSomeTableForAmount = "SomeTable.getSomeTableForAmount";

    @Id
    private String id;
    private BigDecimal startingAmount;
    private BigDecimal endingAmount;
    private BigDecimal minimumDueAmount;
    private Product product;
}
```